# C++ build after generating pre-processed output (VS 08)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, c-preprocessor

I noticed that when I select

```
Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> c/c++ -> Preprocessor -> 
     Generate Proprocessed file -> With Line Numbers (/P)
```

(and other options that generate preprocessed file), no object file is created, so the build fails.  It's like the right hand doesn't know what the left is doing, so there's an error:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '.\Debug\globals.obj'

That makes me think that it might be the case that an object file can be created with command-line `/P`.  Is it possible?  Can I get object files with `\P`?  I read somewhere that I can't, but I would like to put it to the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: You should be able to feed the preprocessed .i file into cl.exe directly.  A preprocessed C++ source file is still a valid C++ source file.  Have you tried adding the .i file to the project and configuring it as a C++ source file?

Comment: @Mr. McNellis, I'd rather not do two steps.  I would like, in one go, for the IDE to create preprocessed output, then compile the project normally.  It's not a big deal, after finding that Alt+Enter quickly gets me to the project properties, It's not as bad going back and forth.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the /P switch is: [Preprocess without compiling or linking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btw8x58e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

So, it doesn't look like there's a way of doing what you'd like to do. (This isn't surprising. The output from /P tends to be rather large, and I doubt that most folks would want to have it generated for every build.)